# React.js POST method issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

I'm doing this React.js project and I have to use POST method. I've managed to make the item appear in the the console and in the json file, but it's not showing in my table. I assume It has to do something with the useEffect hook, but since I'm very new to all of this, I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Table

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Table = () => {
  //FETCH API
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/movies");
      setPosts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  //SORTING
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("ascending");
  const sorting = (s) => {
    if (order === "ascending") {
      const sorted = [...posts].sort((a, b) =>
        a[s].toLowerCase() > b[s].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );

      setPosts(sorted);
      setOrder("descending");
    }

    if (order === "descending") {
      const sorted = [...posts].sort((a, b) =>
        a[s].toLowerCase() < b[s].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setPosts(sorted);
      setOrder("ascending");
    }
  };

  //TABLE
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="click" onClick={() => sorting("name")}>
              Name
            </th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <tr key={post}>
              <td>{post.name}</td>
              <td>{post.genre}</td>
              <td>{post.rating}</td>
              <td>
                {<button className="btn btn-outline-success">delete</button>}
                {<button className="btn btn-outline-warning">edit</button>}
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

AddForm

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function AddForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");
  const [rating, setRating] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/movies", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        genre: genre,
        rating: rating,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });

    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h2>Add a New movie</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          required="required"
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Genre:</label>
        <input
          name="genre"
          type="text"
          required="required"
          onChange={(e) => setGenre(e.target.value)}
        />

        <label>Rating:</label>
        <input
          name="rating"
          type="text"
          required="required"
          onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddForm;
```

Comment: Where is the table you are trying to update?

Comment: I'm struggling to post the code correctly. Gonna try harder :)

Comment: you can try to put e.preventDefault() before the fetch function

Comment: @MostafaHesham figured that one out while I was posting it here, but I'm looking for solution that doesn't require me to refresh the page for it to load. That's why I said I believe it has something to do with the useEffect hook

Comment: So your server is sending you the valid array of movies. You can console them and are confident your fetch and request are also good. But it's not being loaded into react side?

Comment: It loads into the table. It works perfectly fine.. The only issue is that I have to refresh the page for it to show up.

Comment: The `Table` component needs to know to rerender, or refresh, or refetch data. How does these two component related to each other? Does the POST request response return the new data or is a GET request necessary to repull the latest data?

Comment: Eh, you lost me now. I'm seriously very new to this, so I don't truly understand what exactly you asked me.

Comment: You need to add the new post to state. i.e. `setPosts(posts => [...posts, response])` or something along those lines

Comment: Could you please post the response(res.data) from the API? It would be greate to debug with that.

Comment: @B.Anup Again, not quite sure what do you mean. I've posted the entire code here. Like I said, it works fine, it just won't load content until I refresh the page. Now, one guy told me I have to implement useEffect, but I just don't know how or where, I've tried putting the POST method into useEffect, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you check the state of the component in react developer tool, after component is mounted.

Comment: I meant that you need *some* state and/or handlers in a common ancestor component so changes in one component can update shared state and trigger the other component to rerender. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or look into adding redux or similar to your app.